# Lightning Network LND - Retrieve payment by hash

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

How do I get an outgoing `Payment` by `paymentHash` using LND REST API? I know that `GET /v1/payments` returns all payments, but I would like to get one in particular, not all as there may be thousands. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can look up payments by their paymentHash but you can look up invoices which contain a lot of the same information using a paymentHash: https://api.lightning.community/rest/index.html#v1-invoice